# How to do comparison correctly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check that min is always less then max and  min and max value is always a number and min and max is not empty.

I noticed that it never checks for that but goes straight to error msg. What am i doing wrong?

```
var min=30
var max=5000;
if(isNaN(min)=="false" || isNaN(max)=="false") && (min!=""|| max!="") && (max > min))
{
 document.write(min+ max);
}else
{
 document.write("give error msg");
}
```

Comment: Post `isNaN` function?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin isNaN is native JS function

Comment: false is a boolean value, not a string. But you don't need to compare booleans to false (or true), you can just say
if (!isNaN(min) || !isNan(max)) && ...

Comment: `if(min<max && min-max-0.235345345)` usually works (always w/Ints) and is simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use JavaScript `Number()`to check if something is a Number. `NaN` evaluates to false anyhow, so you only have to check if this satisfies ALL your requirements, not some. If `min` is not a number, fail, if `max` is not a number, fail, if `min` is smaller than `max`, fail. This looks like this:

```
var min = 30
var max = 5000;

// You only need to check if its a Number using the default Number function which will
// return NaN if its not and convert if it can be converted.
if(Number(min) && Number(max) && (min <= max)){
    document.write(min + ", " + max);
} else {
    document.write("Min or Max is not a number or Min is bigger than Max");
}
```

Now, as some have pointed out, this will have some edge cases, so heres something that gets around it:

```
function getNumber(n){
    // Take a number 'n' and return 0 if false if its not a number.
    return Number(n) === 0 ? 0 : Number(n) || false;
    // Broken down this means:
    // Check if n is the number 0. Yes? Return 0. No? Check if n is a number. Yes? Return that. No? Return false;
}
if(getNumber(min) !== false && getNumber(max) !== false && (min <= max)){
    document.write(min + ", " + max);
}
```

Or as @IsmaelMigual said in the comments, make it simpler by dividing by 1 and then comparing:

```
function isNumber(n){
    // Returns true or false
    return n / 1 == n / 1;
}
if(isNumber(min) && isNumber(max) && (min <= max)){
    document.write(min + ", " + max);
}
```

Comment: Didnt know about the Number functionality, thanks :)

Comment: @somethinghere how do I make sure that min and max value is not empty? i was trying to add also min!="" and max !=""

Comment: @user244394 I've added a function that will return false if its not a number, otherwise returns the number. Now you can ask it to `getNumber(0)` and it will return `0`. Just make sure to do a type check by checking if the returned is not really the boolean `false`.

Comment: You are overcomplicating! `min / 1 == min` is easier than your whole function. and works as required.

Comment: @somethinghere -as Juhana also pointed out , It fails when  min =11 and max=2 , also  when min=2" and max =2.. it shoudl give an error message for both cases.

Comment: @user244394 Could that be because I decided not to repeat you code twice? The `else` is exactly the same.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Darn it! Thats so simple and elegant :) I added it to the post!

Comment: Now I've noticed... It should be `n / 1 == n / 1`. (You don't have to use `===` since you are already comparing if 2 `Number`s are equal or not). Sorry, My mistake.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yeah I just started noticing this as well, my solution was to _numberify_ around it :) But again, your solution seems more elegant. A long day and my brain is a bit frazzled and overcomplicating...

Comment: `Number(n) / 1 === Number(n)` <-- Don't do this. The `n / 1` is exactly the same as `Number(n)`, but faster. You may use `n + 0` or even `n * 1`. `n / 1` is the easiest to the eye since we **all** know that anything divided by `1` will return itself. You can use `==` safely. The only time that `n != n` is when `n = NaN`. (When you do `NaN == NaN`, it returns false)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Actually that came down to the type setting again, I half-fixed it with `Number` first which did make it work (`Number("1") / 1 === Number("1")`). Although I do have to say this is a case where `===` is a good use for it, just for safety. But yeah I amended it.

Comment: `===` is overkill here. You are already comparing if 2 `Number`s are the same. You don't need to check if the type is the same. `0 == 0` and `0 === 0` work the same, but the first is faster because it doesn't check if they are the same type. The only time you would need `===` is if you dont use `n / 1` on one of the sides. (E.g.: `n / 1 === n`) This one would only work if and only if you introduced a number.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Damn you and your non-frazzled logic. Amended!

Comment: I have no idea what `frazzled` means. But the best way is to keep it simple. It's so much easier to explain the last example than the first. You had to break down in the comments the first example (and it gets worst for those who aren't familiar with it). The last one (provided by me), is much easy to explain even for those who aren't familiar with such technique.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel true. Heres frazzled: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=frazzled Cheers.

Comment: Thank all I have created all  of these in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/j5ctfLs1/

Comment: Thank you a lot for the definition. Learning everyday!

Comment: @user244394 `if(Number(min) && Number(max) && ( max> min)){` Won't work if `min` or `mar` are `0`. `Number(min) == false` will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(isNaN(min)=="false"`  will always return false, because the function will either return `true` or `false`, but never `"false"` (which is a string).

Also, you should have use "and" in the first brackets.
Try this instead: 
`if(! isNaN(min) && ! isNaN(max)) &&` (...)

Edit:
try this condition:
`if((! isNaN(min) && ! isNaN(max)) && max> min && min > 0 ) {` (...)